# How can I get github to use a specific ssh key

Tags: github

I'm getting the following error:

```
no such identity: /users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But I uploaded this repository a week ago using `/users/me/.ssh/fkey`.  I don't want to delete the repository and start all over again.  I need to find out how to use the ssh key that I originally used and prevent github from using id_ed25519.  Also how can I be doubly sure that github really did use fkey a week ago when uploading the depository in question?  In my settings in my github account under ssh keys it clearly says that `fkey`is one of my keys but how do I know that github is linking that key to the repository that I want to push.

Answer (score 0):

In the config file in the .ssh folder I changed

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

to

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /users/me/.ssh/fkey
```